# Nothing returned from for in loop function (react)

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

So I believe I have what is a fairly simple issue, but struggling to uncover an answer.

```
const obj = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
let items;
for (const i in obj) {
    items = `<div>${i}</div>`;
}
return items;
```

Expected result

```
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

Actual result

"Nothing was returned from render.
This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

Comment: is obj meant to be an array?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an array.
Working example:

```
const items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
return items.map(item=>`<div>${item}</div>`)
```

Comment: This would cause a syntax error. `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` is invalid javascript syntax.

Comment: @NateLevin I have updated it. This is the simplest solution

Comment: Looks great, but if an array is being used isn't a key attribute required?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```html
<html>
    <title>test</title>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        const obj = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        let items = '';
        for (const i in obj) {
            items += `<div>${obj[i]}</div>`;
        }

        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += items;
    
    </script>
</html>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This is using React. Appending strings is a bad idea.

Comment: The tags in this question are javascript and for-loop. And yes if it is ReactJs, appending strings isn't a good idea. and the answer will depend on the approach used (Class component or functional component approaches).